# Headphones disable auto-hibernate

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, hibernate, headphones

I want to prevent my Bose Soundlink 2 headphones from hibernating. The headphones will hibernate when I use them in the headset mode even if music is played or I use them in Skype. So it doesn't matter what I do with them in headset mode, they will always turn off after ~15mins. 
In the high-quality stream (usage without microphone) they will hibernate only if they are unused for some time.

What can I do? I am running Mint 17.2. Maybe anybody knows how to disable the hibernation generally (but I guess this functionality is headphone related, right?).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was headphone related. If someone has the same problem, here the solution: Could fix the issue with the Bose [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bose.monet).